# Best Practice on Using a Single SQLAlchemy Engine Across Multiple Async Tasks

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I am running a concurrent process using `asyncio`. To do this, I am constructing a number of orchestrator objects which use this same engine. I am debating if I should be passing this engine or referencing it as a class variable.

I understand that the SQLAlchemy engine is thread safe, but if I pull connections out of it using `async` coroutines is this safe? I am using Snowflake as my database which does not allow direct asyncio integration, so my idea is to run async tasks that involve the data processing (typically API calls, and some minor transformation) and then use the engine to create a connection and run a query.

```
import asyncio

class Orchestrator:
    def __init__(self, engine) -> None:
        self.engine = engine

    async def run(self) -> None:
        # Do some things

        # Run insert query
        await self.insert_data(data)

    async def insert_data(self) -> None:
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE")
            
async def main() -> None:
    # Create orchestrator objects
    orchestrators = create_orchestrators()

    # Run orchestrators which are going to be treated as asynchronous tasks that involve 
    # some data processing and eventual insert into database. 
    # I don't want one orchestrator's activity to block another's
    tasks: list = [
        asyncio.create_task(o.run())
        for o in orchestrators
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```